# Why doesn't the program proceed

Tags: java, recursion, command-line-arguments

The following program is a recursive program to check for repeated entries in an array. The program compiles with no errors, however after i input the command-line arguments and hit enter, it doesn't proceed. The cursor just blinks! It doesn't return any Runtime errors too! If someone explains why this is happening, it'd be very helpful! Thanks! :)

```
import java.io.*;
    class RepeatEntries_Recursive
    {
        static int i=0,flag=0;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            int[] inp = new int[6];
            for(int k=0;k<args.length;k++)
                inp[k] = Integer.parseInt(args[k]);
            boolean hasItRepeated = Repeating(inp,i);
            if(hasItRepeated == true)
                System.out.println("\nYes, there are entries that repeat in the array!");
            else
                System.out.println("\nNo, entries don't repeat in the array");
        }
        static boolean Repeating(int[] inp,int i)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<inp.length;j++)
            {
                if(inp[i] == inp[j])
                    flag = 1;
                while(i<inp.length-1)
                    Repeating(inp,i+1);
            }
            if(flag==1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What arguments are you running this with?

Comment: I'm trying with command line arguments - 12 1 56 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while(i<inp.length-1)
    Repeating(inp,i+1);
```

Your program can't ever escape from this loop.

Comment: Haha, was just about to post that myself

Comment: Not only that, even without the loop the recursion is infinite.

Comment: No, @ᴍarounᴍaroun, I don't think it is.  Without the loop, `i` would eventually reach the length of the array, which stops the recursion.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks for that! :) But how do I make it recursive program and it doesn't loop infinitely! I want the recursion to stop at some point so, I used the while statement.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun anyway to stop the recursion correctly and also avoid infinite looping?

Comment: @Chris anyway to stop the recursion correctly and also avoid infinite looping? Unable to figure out anything!

Comment: Step through it in a debugger and see if `while` really makes sense there. You possibly want `if` so it recurses once at each level, not infinitely at each level.